# How to design a custom file upload button such that the label changes when file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <span id="filename">Select your file</span>
    <label for="file-upload">Browse<input type="file" id="file-upload"></label>
</form>
<script>
$('#file-upload').change(function() 
    var filepath = this.value;
    var m = filepath.match(/([^\/\\]+)$/);
    var filename = m[1];
    $('#filename').text(filename);
});
</script>
```

I just wanted help to implement the submit button such that each would not utilize the separate filename id that we are using here. I am new to js and have many file upload button in my project and when I am using classes every file name change is being reflected only on one button.

Comment: using `ID` attributes for this purpose is not the way to do it. You mention using `classes` - that is better but you need to combine that approach with parent/child/sibling selectors to target and modify the correct HTML elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very quickly cobbled together using vanilla Javascript ~ essentially if there are multiple file input elements and you want the same functionality for each then you would want to obtain a reference to the nodelist collection ( `querySelectorAll` will return a nodelist ) and, for each one, assign a `change` event handler.
Using a combination of `parentNode` and `previousElementSibling` you can identify the `span` element and modify it quite easily.

The actual uploading of the file could be handled by the `change` handler and modifications to the DOM done as a result of this.

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]').forEach( input=>{
        input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.textContent=this.value.match(/([^\/\\]+)$/)[1];
            this.parentNode.textContent='Uploading...';
        });
    });
```

```html
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <span>Select your file</span>
    <label for='file-upload'>Browse<input type='file' /></label>
</form>

<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <span>Select your file</span>
    <label for='file-upload'>Browse<input type='file' /></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! finally, it worked I was messed up on it. I wanted to upvote but don't have the reputation either:-(

Comment: you can possibly "accept" the answer - surprised you cannot "upvote" though... anyway- hope it helps